# Microsoft Office 2010 Excel Add-In (or UDF)

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, add-in

I have created an automation add-in with a UDF that converts a given number into a string (ex. 100 = one hundred); like a class library in Visual Studio 2010 in C#, and it works with MS Excel 2007(x86). I am having a problem when I install it on MS Excel x64. I have created the add in using [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eric_carter/writing-user-defined-functions-for-excel-in-net).
Where and what should be changed to make this thing to work?

Comment: the installer is made according this http://leon.mvps.org/DotNet/RegasmInstaller.html tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To make an answer from the OP's comment.

The installation procedure can be found [here](http://leon.mvps.org/DotNet/RegasmInstaller.html).